# How to edit my query show only one image per product?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, products and product_images. Product_images has entries of images for each product. There are a lot of images per product.

I am using the following SQL query, however I want to show only one image per product. Now I get as many entries per product as the images.

In this purpose I will show a lot of products, like all the products of a category, not a single product.

```
select products.product_id, product_images.image,
       products.name, products.description
from product_images
left join products on products.product_id = product_images.product_id 
where products.category_child= 1
```

How to show only one image (the first) per product?

Comment: @Rizier123 I will not show a single product, but all the products of a category

Comment: @Rizier123 also I was not the one who downvoted you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're OK with a lexicographically smallest image name, then this query will work:

```
select products.product_id,  MIN(product_images.image), products.name, products.description 
from product_images 
     left join 
     products 
     on products.product_id = product_images.product_id 
where products.category_child= 1 
group by products.product_id
```

Also, you probably want to use `INNER JOIN` here instead of `LEFT JOIN`, because `LEFT JOIN` will also return images that belong to no product, if you for some reason have such.

Comment: What if the images have titles?

Comment: Then it gets a little trickier. MySQL doesn't have an easy way to select columns that correspond to the row with the value that MIN aggregate returns. You will either need to use a subquery to retreive that info, or do a more complex join, if perf is critical.

The subselect idea is something like `SELECT products.product_id, MIN(product_images.image) image_url, (SELECT v.title FROM product_imanges v WHERE v.image = image_url) image_title, products.name, ...`